# Breadcrumb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, breadcrumbs

What's the best way to include breadcrumbs in Rails?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1. And what make?
Put breadcrumbs.rb in config/ and after remove Gretel::Crumbs.layout do ... end and I just add


crumb :root do
    link "Home", root_path
end


And put in my application.html.haml this:

= breadcrumbs :pretext => "Você está aqui: ", :separator => " &rsaquo;"

But don't render nothing, just empty, what make?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gretel](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel) is a very good gem for making breadcrumb in rails. It is very easy to use, you can find the tutorial on the same page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There should be no problem using it under ruby 2 and rails 4.

Comment: I'll try and after post here. Thanks!

Comment: Don't work... using version 2.1... don't render the breadcrumb... in my haml is empty

Comment: Please start a new question explaining all the details so others can also help you. You may post the link to the question here at the comment.